# Trouble returning to command options using loops/ only one command is being run (JAVA)

Tags: java, loops

This is my first time on this site. I am taking a course in Java right now and I am having some trouble with this code/program that I am supposed to make that allows the user to select whether they want to see "good monkeys", "bad monkeys" or "show monkeys". It is nowhere near done but I am having trouble returning to the command screen/area after a command is completed. I would like the commands to be used as many times as possible. Secondly, my program treats every input if someone put in "Good Monkey". So if you put in a word like "pineapple", it will still greet you with the output designated for the "Good Monkeys" input.

I've looked online and seen that maybe I should use a "do-while" loop and use "switch". Any input/ help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Here is my code: public class and public static and Scanner import are in this code, but for some reason I cannot add them into this post without messing up the formatting of the code.

```
 Scanner jScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("please enter Good Monkeys, Bad Monkeys or Show Monkeys");
 String userChoice = jScanner.nextLine();   
 for (int b= 1; b < 11000; b++) 
    {
        if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Good Monkeys"));
        {
            System.out.println("You have selected Good Monkeys");
            System.out.println("How many monkeys do you want? Put in a integer between 3 and 20");
            Scanner goodMonkeyScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
            int userChoiceGood = goodMonkeyScanner.nextInt();
            if (userChoiceGood >= 3 && userChoiceGood <= 20)
            {
                System.out.println("Here you go");
                System.out.println("Monkeys (metapohorical)");
            break;
        }
        else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Bad Monkeys"))
        {
            System.out.println("You have selected Bad Monkeys");
            System.out.println("How many monkeys do you want? Put in a integer between 3 and 20");
                Scanner badMonkeyScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
                int userChoiceBad = badMonkeyScanner.nextInt();
                if (userChoiceBad >= 3 && userChoiceBad <= 20)
                {
                    System.out.println("Here you go");
                    System.out.println("Monkeys (metapohorical)");
                    break; 
                }
                else 
                    System.out.println("Sorry this doesn't work");  

        }   

        else if ((userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Show Monkeys")))
        {   
            System.out.println("Monkeys");
            System.out.println("0");
            System.out.println("\\/");
            System.out.println(" |");
            System.out.println("/\\");
            break;
        }
        else 
        {   
            System.out.println(" Wrong Answer. Try again");
        }

        break;
    }

}
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define the loop. Second, you need to put the input instruction *inside* the loop.

I'll include a `done` variable to detect when the user wants to escape

So, let's code:

```
Scanner jScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean done = false;
while(!done) {
    System.out.println("please enter Good Monkeys, Bad Monkeys or Show Monkeys");
    System.out.println("(or enter 'done' to exit");
    String userChoice = jScanner.nextLine();
    swithc(userChoice.toLowerCase()) {
        case "good monkeys":
            /*
             * The code for this option
             */
             break;
        case "bad monkeys":
            /*
             * The code for this option
             */
             break;
        case "show monkeys":
            /*
             * The code for this option
             */
             break;
        case "done":
            done = true;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Your input isn't what I expected!\nTry again!");
            break;
    }
}
```

**The code, explained:**

- That `while(!done)` stuff can be read as "while 'not done' do what follows"
- `userChoice.toLowerCase()`: I convert the `userChoice` to lower-case, to simplify comparissons. That way, I only need to compare the string with other lower-case strings
- `switch(userChoice.toLowerCase())`: ... hmmm... I think you can figure it out yourself ;)

  - That `default` block is what happens if no other case is valid
  - The `"done"` block will set the `done` variable to `true`, and thus it will terminate the loop
  - Important: ***ALWAYS*** end the `case` blocks with `break`

***Further reading:***

- [The Java Tutorials: Language basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html)

  - [The `while` and `do-while` statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)
  - [The `switch` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Also, I recommend you study [Flowcharts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) and, before start coding, try to draw in paper a flowchart of your program. That way, you will have a clear image of your program before you start writing the very first line of code.